# Running time of a job sent to a ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading

Good day,

I am writing a program where a method is called for each line read from a text file. As each call of this method is independent of any other line read I can call them on parallel. To maximize cpu usage I use a ExecutorService where I submit each run() call. As the text file has 15 million lines, I need to stagger the ExecutorService run to not create too many jobs at once (OutOfMemory exception). I also want to keep track of the time each submitted run has been running as I have seen that some are not finishing. The problem is that when I try to use the Future.get method with timeout, the timeout refers to the time since it got into the queue of the ExecutorService, not since it started running, if it even started. I would like to get the time since it started running, not since it got into the queue.

The code looks like this:

```
ExecutorService executorService= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(ncpu);
line = reader.readLine();
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
HashMap<MyFut,String> runs = new HashMap<MyFut, String>();
HashMap<Future, MyFut> tasks = new HashMap<Future, MyFut>();
while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null ) { 

String s = line.split("\t")[1];
final String m = line.split("\t")[0];
MyFut f = new MyFut(s, m);
tasks.put(executorService.submit(f), f);

runs.put(f, line);

while (tasks.size()>ncpu*100){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Iterator<Future> i = tasks.keySet().iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        Future task = i.next();
        if (task.isDone()){
            i.remove();

        } else {
            MyFut fut = tasks.get(task);
            if (fut.elapsed()>10000){
                System.out.println(line);
                task.cancel(true);
                i.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
}

private static class MyFut implements Runnable{

private long start;
String copy;
String id2;

public MyFut(String m, String id){
    super();

    copy=m;
    id2 = id;
}

public long elapsed(){
    return System.currentTimeMillis()-start;
}



@Override
public void run() {
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    do something...
}

}
```

As you can see I try to keep track of how many jobs I have sent and if a threshold is passed I wait a bit until some have finished. I also try to check if any of the jobs is taking too long to cancel it, keeping in mind which failed, and continue execution. This is not working as I hoped. 10 seconds execution for one task is much more than needed (I get 1000 lines done in 70 to 130s depending on machine and number of cpu).

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't the run method in my Runnable class be called only when some Thread in the ExecutorService is free and starts working on it? I get a lot of results that take more than 10 seconds. Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making your work harder as it should be. Java’s framework provides everything you want, you only have to use it.

Limiting the number of pending work items works by using a *bounded queue*, but the `ExecutorService` returned by `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()` uses an unbound queue. The policy to wait once the bounded queue is full can be implemented via a `RejectedExecutionHandler`. The entire thing looks like this:

```
static class WaitingRejectionHandler implements RejectedExecutionHandler {
  public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
    try {
      executor.getQueue().put(r);// block until capacity available
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
      throw new RejectedExecutionException(ex);
    }
  }
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  final int nCPU=Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
  final int maxPendingJobs=100;
  ExecutorService executorService=new ThreadPoolExecutor(nCPU, nCPU, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES,
    new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(maxPendingJobs), new WaitingRejectionHandler());

  // start flooding the `executorService` with jobs here
```

That’s all.

Measuring the elapsed time *within* a job is quite easy as it has nothing to do with multi-threading:

```
long startTime=System.nanoTime();
// do your work here
long elpasedTimeSoFar = System.nanoTime()-startTime;
```

But maybe you don’t need it anymore once you are using the bounded queue.

---

By the way the `Future.get` method with timeout does *not* refer to the time since it got into the queue of the ExecutorService, it refers to the time of invoking the `get` method itself. In other words, it tells how long the `get` method is allowed to wait, nothing more.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am now reading carefully the `ThreadPoolExecutor` and `RejectedExecutionHandler` javadoc pages. I think they would do the job more gracefully than what I coded, although I would still need to code logic to take care of when one job is taking too long (has hanged or some other problem). And thanks for the clarification of the `Future.get` method.

Comment: Keep it mind that cancelling a hanging job requires your task to be able to react on thread interruption. So, heavy computation must poll [`Thread.interrupted()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted()) regularly and blocking (I/O) methods must be interruptible, e.g. be declared to throw `InterruptedException`. This is tricky if you don’t know why some jobs take far longer than expected (in other words, at which operation they are hanging).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Future, I would recommend change Runnable to Callable and return total time in execution of thread as result. Below is sample code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class MyFut implements Callable<Long> {

    String copy;
    String id2;

    public MyFut(String m, String id) {
        super();

        copy = m;
        id2 = id;
    }

    @Override
    public Long call() throws Exception {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //do something...
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return (end - start);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be the same, but more straightforward, solution as mine. OP  seems to be after something else.

Comment: Yeah, I need to check during the do something part how long it has been going on. The thing is some line seem to block indefinitely and will never finish. I would like to know when it is in the do something part how long since it started.

Comment: @Antonio I see your point now. You want to call `elapsed` if the task is still running. Deleting my answer.

Comment: @Antonio Your code is doing it right except that it's not thread-safe: the `start` variable should be `volatile`. But I don't believe that this will change your output.

Comment: I think I have it. The problem seemed to be that I don't initialize `start` in `MyFut`. As such I think it would be zero before run was called. In that case `elapsed` would always give a big number before the job really started. I have now initialized it with value `Long.MAX_VALUE` and it seems to be working.