# How to use preexisting runnables, limiting the number of runnables to create.?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, runnable, executorservice

Problem Statement:

1. I have a 5000 id's that point to rows in a database.[ Could be more than 5000 ]
2. Each Runnable retrieves the row in a database given an id and performs some time consuming tasks

   ```
   public class BORunnable implements Callable<Properties>{

     public BORunnable(String branchID) {            
       this.branchID=branchID;            
     }

     public setBranchId(String branchID){
       this.branchID=branchID;
     }
     public Properties call(){
       //Get the branchID
       //Do some time consuming tasks. Merely takes 1 sec to complete

       return propObj;            
     }
   }
   ```
3. I am going to submit these runnables to the executor service.
4. For that, I need to create and submit 5000 or even more runnables to the executor service. This creation of runnables, in my environment could throw out of memory exception. 
   [given that 5000 is just an example]

So I came up with a approach, I would be thankful if you provide anything different:

1. Created a thread pool of fixed size 10.

   ```
   int corePoolSize = 10;
   ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, 
       corePoolSize + 5, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 
       new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());

   Collection<Future<Properties>> futuresCollection = 
       new LinkedList<Future<Properties>>();
   ```
2. Added all of the branchIDs to the branchIdQueue

   ```
   Queue<String> branchIdQueue = new LinkedList<String>();
   Collections.addAll(branchIdQueue, branchIDs);
   ```
3. I am trying to reuse runnable. Created a bunch of runnable

   Now i want this number of elements to be dequeued and create runnable for each

   ```
   int noOfElementsToDequeue = Math.min(corePoolSize, branchIdQueue.size());

   ArrayList<BORunnable>runnablesList = dequeueAndSubmitRunnable(
       branchIdQueue,noOfElementsToDequeue);


   ArrayList<BORunnable> dequeueAndSubmitRunnable(branchIdQueue,
       noOFElementsToDequeue){
   ArrayList<BORunnable> runnablesList= new ArrayList<BORunnable>();
       for (int i = 0; i < noOfElementsToDequeue; i++) {
           //Create this number of runnables
           runnablesList.add(new BORunnable(branchIdQueue.remove()));
       }
   return runnablesList;
   }
   ```
4. Submitting the retrieved runnables to the executor

   ```
   for(BORunnable boRunnableObj:runnablesList){
        futuresCollection.add(executor.submit(boRunnableObj));
   }
   ```
5. If the queue is empty, I created the runnables I needed. if it's not, I want to reuse the runnable and submit to the executor.
6. Here I get number of runnables to be reused = the total count - current active count 
   [Approximate is enough for me]

   ```
   int coreSize=executor.getCorePoolSize();

   while(!branchIdQueue.isEmpty()){

       //Total size - current active count 
       int runnablesToBeReused=coreSize-executor.getActiveCount();
       if(runnablesToBeReused!=0){
           ArrayList<String> branchIDsTobeReset = removeElementsFromQueue(
               branchIdQueue,runnablesToBeReused);
           ArrayList<BORunnable> boRunnableToBeReusedList = 
               getBORunnableToBeReused(boRunnableList,runnablesToBeReused);
           for(BORunnable aRunnable:boRunnableList){
               //aRunnable.set(branchIDSTobeRest.get(0));
           }
       }

   }
   ```

My Problem is

1. I couldn't able to find out which Runnable has been released by the thread pool so i could use that to submit
2. Hence,  I randomly take few runnables and try to set the branchId, but then thread race problem may occur. [don't want to use volatile]

Comment: Why not just use the branchidQueue and create BORunnable directly when submitting it? I don't see why you need `runnablesList`. So you would save that memory.

Comment: Trying to avoid iteration in BORunnable. If there is an iteration in a runnable, then it's of no use for a mulithreading concept.

Comment: Why don't you use Future.isDone()? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html

Comment: No not **inside** the runnable. I mean `for(String id:branchidQueue){
     futuresCollection.add(executor.submit(new BORunnable(id)));
}` well, just with dequeing, but you know what I mean. Just leaving out the ArrayList - step.

Comment: @Fildor 
Creation of BoRunnable may result in out of memory exception in JVM environment. There is no specified limit in number of BoRunnable object creation.

Comment: @inigoD want to reuse the runnable. I don't think Future is gonna solve the problem.

Comment: I do not think introducing the complexity of a BORunnable-Pool will help. I even think it will make things worse. Are you even sure it is the BORunnable Objects that lead to OOM? I suspect the results to be much bigger than those little BORunnables. But outside of that, I think you should put some kind of hard limit. Maybe even introduce pagination.

Comment: The Executors have a lot of possibilites to set Limits, too, by the way. You could use a bounded Queue to block the Producer if the Queue is getting too big ... just to begin with.

Comment: There is no such thing as a Runnable.  Sometimes we say, "a Runnable," but what we really mean is, "an instance of a class that _implements_ Runnable."  Implementing runnable puts no limits on what a class may or may not do:  It only means that the class must have a public void instance method named run().  The question of whether or not an instance can be re-used, or what it can be used _for_ are entirely up to how you design the class.

Comment: @jameslarge but the run  method i am using depends on the state of the instance. if one runnable given to two different threads and with two different states, racing could occur.

Comment: @Fildor Thanks for your input. if i am putting a limit on the bounded queue, it will restrict the other runnables from adding to the queue. i want all of the runnables to run but delaying the creation of the runnable.

Comment: @surendhar_s See Holger's answer. I guess you misunderstand how limiting the Executor's Queue will affect the adding behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Reusing the `Runnable`s makes no sense as the problem is not the cost of creating or freeing the runnable instances. These come almost for free in Java.

What you want to do is to *limit* the number of pending jobs which is easy to achieve: just provide a *limit* to the queue you are passing to the executor service. That’s as easy as passing an `int` value (the limit) to the [`LinkedBlockingQueue`’s constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#LinkedBlockingQueue(int)). Note that you can also use an [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) then as a `LinkedBlockingQueue` does not provide an advantage for bounded queue usage.

When you have provided a limit to the queue, the executor will reject queuing up new jobs. The only thing left to do is to provide an appropriate [`RejectedExecutionHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RejectedExecutionHandler.html) to the executor. E.g. [`CallerRunsPolicy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy.html) would be sufficient to avoid that the caller creates more new jobs while the threads are all busy and the queue is full.

After execution, the `Runnable`s are subject to garbage collection.

Comment: Thanks for your input. If you provide a limit to the queue, it will reject all the other runnables i am trying to add, i don't want that to happen. This is my problem, Create and add runnable only when the queue is empty enough to hold one or more runnables.

Comment: @surendhar_s: maybe you should (re)read the part with the `RejectedExecutionHandler` and `CallerRunsPolicy` carefully.

Comment: If you don’t like `CallerRunsPolicy` you may look at `WaitingRejectionHandler` [from this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20398130/2711488). What both have in common is that all runnables *will* run, it’s only slowing the submitting thread down in creating new runnables. Which is *exactly* what you want.